# Reset ID and secret key for accounts-facebook in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I installed accounts-facebook and facebook-config-ui in my Meteor project. I was having some issues getting it to work so I deleted my app from https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ to start again.

However in my Meteor app Im getting the same error and I don't have an option to add a new ID and secret key. GIT isn't showing me anything on the file system so Ive no idea how to change this.

This is my error:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data is stored in the database. Simple delete those tables.